# Run observable in parallel for each item in a list without waiting

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I've been trying to use mergeMap to solve this problem but I don't think it's correct.

I have a method **getNumbers()** with an http request that returns a list of numbers (**Observable<number[]>**)

I have a service with another method **getData()**, containing an http request that gets data for a given number (**Observable**)

I need to run the first request, then for each number in the result, I want to run the second request. I want all of these to be fired off in parallel, and to not wait for the response. The logic that runs after each one is exactly the same.

Here is my current solution **without** using rxjs

```
this.getNumbers().subscribe((nums: number[]) => {
    nums.forEach((num: number) => {
        this.myService.getData(num).subscribe((response: Data) => {
            this.rows.push(response);
        })
    })
});
```

The behavior is correct but it uses nested subscribes, **and** I can't check whether or not this loop has finished properly. I have a loading spinner that I would like to set to false when all of the calls in the loop are done, but I need rxjs for that.

How can I reformat this properly? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clean up your answer a bit as well.

```ts
// You only ever need to pipe once. .pipe().pipe() is reduntant
this.loadingData$ = this.getNumbers().pipe(
  
  // switchMap turns any iteratble into a a stream automatically.
  switchMap(nums => nums),
  // Single-line lambdas don't need braces {} or return statements
  mergeMap(num => this.myService.getData(num))

).subscribe(response => this.rows.push(response));
```

Optionally, instead of transforming into a stream of numbers,
you can transform your array into an array of observables and
`merge` them all.

```ts
this.loadingData$ = this.getNumbers().pipe(

  switchMap(nums => merge(...nums.map( 
    this.myService.getData.bind(this.myService)
  )))

).subscribe(this.rows.push.bind(this.rows));
```

Answer (score 0):

After some more research, this is the solution I came up with:

```
this.loadingData$ = this.getNumbers().pipe(
            switchMap(nums => {
                return from(nums);
            })
      ).pipe(
            mergeMap(num => {
                return this.myService.getData(num);
            })
        ).subscribe(response => {
            this.rows.push(response);
        })
```

and in my template I can just check

```
if (this.loadingData$.closed)
```

to show or hide the spinner

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you can use `forkJoin` with `RxJS` operators like the following:

```js
this.getNumbers()
  .pipe(
    tap(() => (this.loading = true)),
    switchMap((nums) =>
      forkJoin(nums.map((num) => this.myService.getData(num)))
    ),
    finalize(() => (this.loading = false))
  )
  .subscribe((nums: Data[]) => {
    this.rows.push(nums);
  });
```

Comment: I believe he wants to get intermediate results, which you won't have with forkJoin. It'll wait to have them all. But I could be wrong on the expectation from OP